# Cómo hacer para no cortar palabras de un texto en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando que corte la oración
en cadenas que no rebasen el largo recibido y que no corte ninguna palabra.

Espero puedan ayudarme y haya dado a entenderme, de antemano muchas gracias.

Mi código es el siguiente:

**Codigo***

```js
let maximo = 18;
let frase = 'La niña paseaba a su perro. Vestía un traje azul y chupaba una paleta';

frase = frase.split('');

let palabra = ' ';

frase.forEach(e => {
  if (palabra.length + e.length < maximo) {
    palabra += e;
  } else {
    console.log(palabra);
    palabra = e;
  }
});
```

Comment: Si el método cumpliese con las restricciones que dices, cuál es el resultado que esperas y cuál es el resultado que obtienes?

Comment: 18 son la cantidad de caracteres o de palabras?

Comment: 18 son la cantidad de caracteres, por lo tanto en la primera linea mostrara hasta "La niña paseaba a " y abajo continuaría con toda la frase . En mi ejemplo corta las palabras y no muestra toda la frase completa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad, no se porque, te dieron una respuesta correcto, que luego eliminaron, y a la que solo le faltaba un detalle la salida.
Si el autor original la recupera, bienvenido sea. Pero si no, lo que se hizo fue solo adaptar un detalle de tu codigo.

Se corto la cadena no por letra, si no por palabras (usando el espacio para separarlas).

Y yo agregue, al final, otro console log, para mostrar el resultado de la ultima linea que era lo unico que faltaba.

```js
let maximo = 18;
let frase = 'La niña paseaba a su perro. Vestía un traje azul y chupaba una paleta';

frase = frase.split(' ');

let palabra = ' ';

frase.forEach(e => {
  if (palabra.length + e.length < maximo) {
    palabra += e + " ";
  } else {
    console.log(palabra);
    palabra = " " + e + " ";
  }
});
console.log(palabra);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Es lo que estaba buscando. En verdad te agradezco

Comment: jeje, bueno, era ese el detalle que faltaba =)

Comment: @Cris223511.dev dejabas tu respuesta, nos dabamos cuenta entre todos del error, y yo no tenia que plagiarte flagrantemente... jejejejej

Comment: @FrancoMirandaMichael recuerda leer el [tour] y que aca la forma de agradecer es aceptando la respuesta que soluciono tu problema....